# object of type 'NoneType' has no len() - importing env variables within selenium project

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables

I'm currently building out a program that logs into a website and checks the orders that have come in for the day.

I want to handle the sensitive information required (username and password) using a .env file.

In my .env file I have the following;

```
username=user
password=pass
```

the code I'm using for the login is as follows;

```
load_dotenv()

username = os.getenv('username')
password = os.getenv('password')

username_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id, 'username')]")))
password_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id, 'login')]")))

username_input.send_keys(username)
password_input.send_keys(password)
```

The code works and logs in successfully when storing the username and password directly in the function as below;

```
username_input.send_keys("user")
password_input.send_keys("pass")
```

but when trying to import the variables from the .env file, the username is input correctly but the password returns me the error;

```
object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

really struggling to see the issue, thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `username = os.getenv('username')` The variable "username" was not found in the environment, so the function returned None.

Comment: Either there is no `.env` file in the current directory, or it does not contain a `username` variable setting.

Comment: I've removed the tags now @DeepSpace, the username variable does get found though, and it populates correctly, the issue is only with the password variable. There is definitely no spelling error or hidden spaces etc so I'm really lost on why one is working and the other is not.

Comment: Print the value of `password` after reading it from the environment.  Does it appear correctly?

Comment: @JohnGordon no it returns None, Im really lost. Both variables in my env file are formatted the same, but the username prints correctly, just the password doesnt.

Comment: Either your .env file has some formatting problem, or the code is reading a different .env file than you thought.  This code will look in the _current directory_ for the .env file.  Try `print(os.getcwd())` to confirm the current directory.

Comment: Are you using Windows? apparently, the env variable `username` is already available, so actually, your `load_dotenv` does not work. Try it with another env var that is not `username`.

Comment: In that case, add `override=True` as an arg to load_dotenv.

Comment: It's printing the correct directory, @DeepSpace this is really interesting. I changed "username" variable to "login" and now the username is not populating correctly either and is returning the same error, so I'm assuming the program is not reading my .env file. Does the name of the file matter, mine is called data.env, am I being stupid and its supposed to just be a blank .env file name?

Comment: @Conor yes, of course it matters. It should be `.env` (that's why it is called dotenv, after all...)

Comment: wow thats embarassing, I assumed it could be anything it just needed the .env ending, sorry and thank you for all the help! Its working now.